# Is there a word like "conjugate" that means switching a noun between plural and singular forms?

Tags: nouns, terminology

Changing a verb to reflect the number of people and tense of the sentence is called conjugation.

Is there a word that means toggling a noun between singular and plural?

ie. "The computer program could construct basic sentences, but it could not *pluralify* nouns correctly".

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pluralize

Comment: But "pluralize" only goes one way, from singular to plural. I was looking for something that meant "to set the correct pluralness", even if the correct "pluralness" is singular.

Comment: "...but it could not handle noun plurality correctly"?

Comment: @Nick In the context of the sentence you gave, "pluralize" can be understood to have exactly that meaning.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Verbs are conjugated. Nouns are *declined,* and different ways of doing that are called *declensions*.

> **decline** (In the grammar of Latin, Greek, and certain other languages) state the forms of (a noun, pronoun, or adjective) corresponding to case, number, and gender.
>
> [[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/decline)]

However, changing the word to account for number (for example, adding an *-s*) is a form of *inflection.* Adjectives in English are not inflected for number: the same form is used no matter how many things are being described.

> **inflect** *Grammar* Change the form of (a word) to express a particular grammatical function or attribute, typically tense, mood, person, number, and gender
>
> [[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/inflect)]

Comment: However, I've never heard the word _decline_ used of a language which shows only number and not case in its nouns.

Comment: @ColinFine me neither but it still fits the pattern of declension.

Comment: It may do, but I believe that if you used _decline_ in @Nick's sentence, most people would go "Huh?" and those that were familiar with a language which has case marking would go "But English doesn't mark cases". Hardly anybody would understand it to mean "pluralis/ze" unless there is a pretty clear implication from context.

Comment: English does mark cases in pronouns.

Comment: @ColinFine English marks possessive case with *'s*, though that is properly a clitic.

Comment: @ColinFine - Those are valid points, but it's worth noting that the O.P. didn't ask for a common term, or a widely-known term.

Comment: *Decline* is, I think, the right answer.  There is little declension remaining in English, as noted.  Usually just plural.  Q: decline "woman".  A: "woman, women".

Comment: Declination and conjugation are just subsets of inflection.

Answer (score 3):

Having had regard to @Andrew Leach, in his answer, and the comments it provoked, I think the all important word is ***number***.

However ***number*** would be a difficult term to use without there being ambiguity. Saying that *the program could not specify number* would introduce the idea that you needed quantity specified in some way.

Can't you just get by with ***could not specify nouns as singular or plural***?

Comment: Or "could not accurately distinguish singular and plural nouns", or "could not properly assign number to nouns".

Comment: @ralph.m By all means use the first one, but I think it inevitable that the second has the potential to create misunderstanding - for the reasons I explained.

Answer (score 1):

I am not as knowledged as others here about our English language, but I did stumble across this:
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/singularisation

I suppose one verb would be "singularise". It feels right to use, although I must admit I can't recall it ever being used and additionally I find the spelling to be odd.

Based of speech, I would personally spell it & sound-it-out like 'singulise' (sing-gul-lise).

Regardless though, The word sounds right to me and I would think most native english speaking people would understand the context without much problem, but either way the spelling does still looks strange to me.

the only other thing I was wondering, is whether you could simply say "depluralise" which would effectively imply the same thing.

This is a really VERY intriguing question you have raised! :)